# Removing OU from group of ous using python

Tags: python

iam looking for python code to remove "var1" from "ougrpstr", please note that both variables will change i just want to strip var1 string from group.
basically "var1" representing a user and i am trying remove that user from a particular group.

`var1=  cn=656067688988,cn=Subscribers,cn=inc,cn=apac,cn=dac,cn=Resources,cn=Users,cn=OSILA`  `ougrpstr= "cn=656067689862,cn=Subscribers,cn=inc,cn=apac,cn=dac,cn=Resources,cn=Users,cn=OSILA;cn=656067680730,cn=Subscribers,cn=inc,cn=apac,cn=dac,cn=Resources,cn=Users,cn=OSILA;cn=656067688988,cn=Subscribers,cn=inc,cn=apac,cn=dac,cn=Resources,cn=Users,cn=OSILA;cn=656067686985,cn=Subscribers,cn=inc,cn=apac,cn=dac,cn=Resources,cn=Users,cn=OSILA"`

Comment: what format is the entire thing? Is it a string?

Comment: i extracted these values using beautifulsoap

Comment: `scripts = soup.findAll("script")
        data1 = str(scripts[4])
#        print data1
        data = data1.split('"')
        print data[5]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an exact (case-dependent) match is OK, then you can use `replace`, as in:

```
newstr = ougrpstr.replace(var1, '')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working for me but its adding null value also     example                      `cn=Users,cn=OSILA;;cn=656067688988,`

Comment: modified the code like this ,`out  = data[5].replace(user, '').replace(";;", ";")`, now its working as expected , is this correct way

Comment: That's what I would do, unless I was sure the part I was replacing wouldn't be last, when I would add the `';'` to var1.  Your mod is very sensible.

Comment: in this case i am facing another issue, if the var1 is coming in first field replace still keeping ";" with next field see  output   `;cn=656067680730,cn=Subscribers,cn=inc,cn=apac,cn=dac,cn=Resources,cn=Users,cn=OSILA;cn=656067688988,`

Comment: In that case, you may want to try the replace twice, first with `';'` appended, then without.  If you do that, you don't need to replace `';;'`, so you're still only doing two calls to `replace`.  You could also use regular expressions, but that's not less code (although not much more).

Comment: out  = data[5].replace(e, '').replace(";;", ";").strip(';') this one helped me thanks for your help